# Receive a string via RFCOMM in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to recieve a string via RFCOMM in android

I am a newbie to android and please help me
I can send data
but receiving fails

Here is my code

Please help me

```
package com.example.btspp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Buttons extends Activity {

private BluetoothAdapter btAdaptor;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private OutputStream outStream = null;
private InputStream inStream = null;
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

Thread workerThread;
byte[] readBuffer;
int readBufferPosition;
int counter;
volatile boolean stopWorker;

public String addressToConnect;
public static StringBuilder readStr;

TextView tv;
int aa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buttons);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    addressToConnect = getIntent().getStringExtra("addressToConnect");

    connectToDevice(addressToConnect);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendData("H");          

            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), addressToConnect,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



}





private void sendData(String message) {
    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
    try {
        // final BT bt = new BT();
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        //readData();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Not Sent BT Data : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}


/*private void readData(){
    String instring = "";
    try {
        inStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
    scan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n]+"));
    instring = scan.next();
    scan = null;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Got Data : " + instring, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    //return instring;

}*/
void beginListenForData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {                
           while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
           {
                try 
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = inStream.available();                        
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        inStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        tv.setText(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
           }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
}

private void connectToDevice(String address) {
    btAdaptor = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdaptor.getRemoteDevice(address);
    try {
        btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        btSocket.connect();
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        inStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
        beginListenForData();
        tv.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
        //listenForMessages(btSocket, readStr);
        // beginListenForData();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // errorExit("Fatal Error",
        // "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() +
        // ".");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Not Connected : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_buttons, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I am a newbie to android and please help me
I can send data
but receiving fails

Here is my code

Please help me

Comment: Are there any errors in the log or is it just not working?

Comment: No any errors
It just not works
When I press send
It sends letter "H" successfully to the Bluetooth Serial Port of PC 
But when I type something on on it 
It won't displayed on textview

Comment: There might be an exception as you only stop the receiving thread instead of handling any events... you might want to check if you thread stops running if you try to send data from the pc and also print the stack trace

Comment: Indeed, at **minimum** you need e.printStackTrace() in each catch block, so you can see the failures in logcat.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't 13 "\r" the usual delimiter and not 10?

Comment: this type of post should be placed in comment section